# predict the output

Tags: c

```
void call(int x,int y,int z)
{
  printf("%d   %d  %d",x,y,z);
}
int main()
{
  int a=10;
  call(a,a++,++a);
  return 0;
}
```

this program is giving different output on different compiler and when i compiled it on linux m/c output was quite weird,any reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the behaviour is undefined. The compiler is allowed to evaluate `a`, `a++` and `++a` in any order before passing them to `call()`. (Technically, because we've invoked undefined behaviour, it actually doesn't have to do anything in particular at this point; it may write whatever code it pleases.) Depending on what order they're evaluated in, the results differ.

Comment: but the order of evaluation when value is passed to function is done with stack so there must be some order..

Comment: Yes, but the order can vary from compiler to compiler, and as Karl says, behaviour is undefined so it can do anything, including crashing.

Comment: @user531802 That's irrelevant. The compiler is allowed by the C language standard to evaluate those three arguments in any order, to ease the job of the compiler writer and perhaps increase opportunities for optimization.

Comment: if it done with a stack then order will be either from left to right or vice versa.compile it on linux machine and please check u will be surprised.

Comment: @justin how can we know that how function parameter is passed within a specific compiler.

Comment: @user531802 You shouldn't depend on the behavior even if you can successfully identify what happens in a given case. Since the standard refers to it as undefined behavior, the compiler can literally do whatever it wants when it encounters that code. Even if it generates valid code, the order of operations might vary even between two builds on the same compiler and platform.

Comment: No, it won't. Just because arguments are put onto the stack in a particular order does not mean they were evaluated in the same order. Arguments can be passed in registers anyway. The entire function call could be inlined. If the value of `a` can be determined at compile-time, the calculation might be done statically and constants pushed onto the stack (or put into registers, or substituted into inlined code). Many strange and magical things can happen. Just because two implementations do two different but simple-to-understand things doesn't mean **anything**. You have **no** guarantees here.

Comment: i want to write my own compiler can you please suggest where to start... thnx in advance.

Comment: Start by going to university and taking the relevant courses. This is **not** a simple task.

Comment: @prp: going to university is not a bad idea, but begin by reading the Dragon Book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29 like everyone else.

Comment: The Dragon book teaches how to implement various things that are relatively simple. It's worth a little towards understanding how existing implementations work for complex languages like C++, but not much. Still a worthy read though.

Comment: @kriss thnx for ur suggestion..:)